Cannot redirect to Keycloak login page on Nginx deployed Angular app
I need to deploy an Angular app to an Nginx server on an Amazon EC2 machine. The app uses keycloak-js and keycloak-angular to interface with a Keycloak server hosted on the same EC2 machine.
I built the app with ng build and transfered the files to the machine. This is how I then edited the nginx.conf file:
Added the following lines to http section to enable HTTPS/SSL (I am currently using a self-signed certificate):
ssl_certificate     /root/certs/MyCertificate.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /root/certs/MyKey.key;
ssl_ciphers         EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

Added this server block to rewrite all HTTP URIs to HTTPS:
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    return       301 https://localhost$request_uri;
}

Added this server block to host the app on HTTPS:
server {
    listen       443 ssl default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /var/srv/mysite;
    index        index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

But when I try to open the app on my browser it doesn't redirect to the Keycloak login page, and after some time the console gives me this error: "Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message".
This is the configuration I supplied to keycloak-js through the factory function initializeKeycloak:
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: "http://localhost:8080",
        realm: "test",
        clientId: "test-client",
      },
      loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,
      initOptions: {
        checkLoginIframe: false,
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.html'
      },
      enableBearerInterceptor: true
    });
}

I thought this could be a header handling problem, so I also tried adding these lines to the location / subsection:
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

But nothing changed, still the same error.
Everything works locally (if I am testing on my machine, not EC2). Is there something I forgot? Or something I am doing wrong?

Using return 301 https://localhost$request_uri; directive you are redirecting all client browser requests to the client local machine, not your Amazon EC2 instance, as the localhost domain name from the client computer perspective is referring to its own computer. Use your Amazon EC2 server assigned domain, or at least its IP address.
